# Jetty Server always returning 404 with Handler

Tags: java, http, jetty

I am working on a project and I am trying to create a server listening in the localhost address on port 8082 (I already have 8081 reserved with another server)

```
 public class Class2HTTPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 object1= new Class1 (300);// parameter I need for other stuff
        Class2 object2= new Class2 (300,object1,5); // parameters for other unrelated stuff
        int listen_on_port = 8082;
        Class2HTTPMessageHandler handler = new Class2HTTPMessageHandler (
            object2);
        String server_port_string = System.getProperty(SystemConstants.PROPERTY_KEY_SERVER_PORT);
        if(server_port_string != null) {
            try {
                listen_on_port = Integer.parseInt(server_port_string);
                listen_on_portfs = Integer.parseInt(server_port_string);
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
        ComponentHTTPServerUtility.createServer(listen_on_port, handler);

    }
}
```

This is the ComponentHTTPServerUtility class:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class ComponentHTTPServerUtility {
    /**
     * Creates a server on the port and blocks the calling thread
     * @param port
     * @param handler
     * @return 
     */
    public static boolean createServer(int port, AbstractHandler handler) {
        Server server = new Server(port);
        if (handler != null) {
            server.setHandler(handler);
        }

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a server on the InetAddress and blocks the calling thread
     * @param ipAddress
     * @param port
     * @param handler
     * @return 
     */
    public static boolean createServer(String ipAddress, int port,
            AbstractHandler handler) {
        InetAddress inetIpAddress;
        InetSocketAddress address;
        Server server;

        if (ipAddress == null)
            return false;

        try {
            inetIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
            address = new InetSocketAddress(inetIpAddress, port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        server = new Server(address);
        if (handler != null) {
            server.setHandler(handler);
        }

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run the Server I get the following message in the console:

```
2015-01-19 13:13:49.451:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
2015-01-19 13:13:49.501:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082
```

But If I go with my browser to :
    http://localhost:8082/

I get Error 404. However if I do the same with the other server(port 8081) I get a blank page indicating that the server is running.

Sorry but I cannot get into any more specific. Any thoughts or suggestions would be highly appreciated. I have been stuck at this for hours.

Thanks

EDIT:

These are the results i get for both servers after inserting the line:

System.err.println(server.dump());

Working one:

```
2015-01-19 15:37:05.600:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
2015-01-19 15:37:05.651:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2090b38d - STARTED
 +- com.project.server.Class1HTTPMessageHandler@35f3198f - STARTED
 |
 +- qtp831407528{8<=6<=8/254,0} - STARTED
 |   +- 10 qtp831407528-10 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 11 qtp831407528-11 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 12 qtp831407528-12 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 13 qtp831407528-13 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 14 qtp831407528-14 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 |   +- 15 qtp831407528-15 Selector0 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 16 qtp831407528-16 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 17 qtp831407528-17 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |
 +- SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081 - STARTED
     +- PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@16384,0/1024@-]/PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@32768,0/1024@-] - STARTED
     +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@42557280 - STARTED
     |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@77d05385 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
     |       +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:569)
     |       +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@4611dca9 keys=0
     +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081]
     +- qtp831407528{8<=6<=8/254,0} - STARTED
```

And these are from the non working one:

```
2015-01-19 15:37:23.231:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
2015-01-19 15:37:23.280:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@183c97db - STARTED
 +- com.project.server.Class2HTTPMessageHandler@33767f84     - STARTED
 |
 +- qtp597321988{8<=6<=8/254,0} - STARTED
 |   +- 10 qtp597321988-10 Selector0 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
 |   +- 11 qtp597321988-11 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 12 qtp597321988-12 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 13 qtp597321988-13 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 14 qtp597321988-14 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 |   +- 15 qtp597321988-15 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 16 qtp597321988-16 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 17 qtp597321988-17 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |
 +- SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082 - STARTED
     +- PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@16384,0/1024@-]/PooledBuffers [0/1024@6144,0/1024@32768,0/1024@-] - STARTED
     +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@7f39425c - STARTED
     |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@833e745 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
     |       +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:569)
     |       +- sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@32787e9f keys=0
     +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8082]
     +- qtp597321988{8<=6<=8/254,0} - STARTED
```

The basic handler declaration:

```
public class Class2HTTPMessageHandler extends AbstractHandler{
     private Class2 object= null;

    public Class2HTTPMessageHandler(Class2 obj){
        object= obj;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        MessageTag messageTag;

        String  requestURI;
        Response fieldResponse = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        if (!ComponentUtility.isEmpty(requestURI)
                && requestURI.toLowerCase().startsWith("/stock")) {
            messageTag = ComponentUtility.convertURItoMessageTag(requestURI
                .substring(6)); // the request is from store
            // manager, more
            // sophisticated security
            // features could be added
            // here
        } else {
                messageTag = ComponentUtility.convertURItoMessageTag(requestURI);
        }
        // the RequestURI before the switch
        if (messageTag == null) {
                System.out.println("Unknown message tag");
        } else {
            switch (messageTag) {
                // handling of various messages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to send to the server a message tag and this is the exception I get:

```
 2015-01-19 18:16:43.739:WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/MESSAGETAG
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.project.business.Class2.functionFoo(Class2.java:98)
    at com.project.server.Class2HTTPMessageHandler.handle(Class2HTTPMessageHandler.java:69)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: add after the `server.start();` the line `System.err.println(server.dump());` and report the results.  (Its likely that the handler wasn't set on the server).  Also include the source for `Class2HTTPMessageHandler` (as there are ways to code the handler so that a 404 still occurs)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt just added the results in the question

Comment: Looks like the handler is present and started. (odd that you have a different handler in the first one vs the second one).  What does the handler implementation do?  Can you include the source for the handler? (interested in the declaration, and all of the manipulation of the various request manipulations, including any handle(d|r) state declarations)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added as much of the declaration I could along with the expeption I get when I send a messagetag. To me it still seems that it cant find the server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using Handlers you have to tell the server when your handler has actually handled the request.

Don't forget to call [`baseRequest.setHandled(true);`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.6.v20141205/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/HelloHandler.java#L69)

Without this call, the handler completes and then moves onto the next handler, which in your case would be the default handler that returns 404.

Also, when working with Handlers, use the parameters the Handler is giving you.  The `target` parameter will have the path that was provided, as it was seen on the raw request.

The `request.getRequestURI()` behavior relies on various `ServletContext` information, and as such isn't likely to be the results you are expecting when not using a `ServletContext`.

*Note: if you, in fact, want a `ServletContext` and normal servlet behavior could be had with use of `ServletContextHandler` and real servlets, also within embedded mode. [See `ManyServletContexts` example.](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.6.v20141205/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyServletContexts.java)*

However, it is even easier to handle this situation.  Create a `ContextHandlerCollection` and set each Handler of yours into that collection via a `ContextHandler`.  See the [`ManyContexts` example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.6.v20141205/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyContexts.java).

Example:

```
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
server.setHandler(contexts);

ContextHandler stock = new ContextHandler("/stock");
stock.setHandler(new Class2HTTPMessageHandler());
contexts.add(stock);
```

With this, you can skip the entire check on the Requested URI, and let Jetty handle that.

It should be noted that even Jetty uses the `target` parameter of a `Handler` to perform this context logic.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was stuck for 2 days! :D

Comment: your welcome, just fixed the title to be a bit more accurate to the problem.

Comment: Yes, as Joakim mentioned, baseRequest.setHandled(true) has to be done from within the handler code, after processing of the request is complete.